# Emacs in OSX Terminal.app not filling entire window

Tags: themes, terminal-emacs

I recently (finally) figured out how to get a monokai theme onto my emacs in the default Terminal app, but emacs still isn't filling up the entire window.

There's a small, but noticeable color discrepancy on the corners.

How do I make Emacs fill up the whole Terminal screen?

Note: This occurs in both windowed and "fullscreen" mode. My resolution is 1440 x 900 (Macbook Air 2015 resolution). However, I do use multiple monitors frequently, so a general solution would be very much preferred. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's not the fringe?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you define what the fringe is? It's using the same theme as my default terminal (different kind of Monokai, I believe).

Comment: See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fringe-Size_002fPos.html  If you evaluate this, does the problem disappear?  `(set-window-fringes (selected-window) 0 0 nil)`  You could also try adding the following to your `.emacs` file and restart Emacs:  `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(left-fringe . 0)) (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(right-fringe . 0))`  If you like the fringe, you can keep it but change the color to match the `'default` background color.

Comment: No it doesn't. Added it to the end of .emacs, and didn't make a difference.

Comment: If you get rid of the theme, does your problem go away?  The function `set-window-fringes` operates on the current window when the function is evaluated, not globally.  Evaluate means:  `M-x eval-expression` -- so it is not something that is just added to the `.emacs` file unless you programmatically determine which window is selected when the function gets called during startup.  The `default-frame-alist` is a different story.

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification! I just realized that if I disable the theme, the same "border" exists. Seems to not be the theme, fortunately.

Comment: I just tried this with the latest stable public release for OSX and was not able to duplicate the issue using a blank/empty `.emacs` file [i.e., no user configuration] and the following command line from within Terminal.app:  `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw`  I downloaded it from:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  It is version 24.5.1.  I'm running OSX 10.6.8 Snow Leopard Server.

Comment: I downloaded Emacs from Homebrew (just because of the ease of management). Excuse me, my resolution is still 1440x900, if that changes anything.

Comment: Also, I'm running OSX Yosemite and Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: If you type `M-x eval-expression RET (window-fringes) RET` -- do you get?:  **(0 0 nil)**

Comment: I do get (0 0 nil)

Answer (score 3):

Terminal.app has slight margins on the each end. This works fine for terminal commands, but it also adds an unwanted margin to your "full-screen" terminal applications. I don't think there is any preference to remove these margins in Terminal.app

One solution is to use a patched copy of iTerm2. You can download the source from iTerm2's github repository, and apply [this patch](https://gist.github.com/anuragm/ab71c54508cb4e7667abe60e482b2210). Adjust the margin to your liking.

Another option is to set the Terminal.app background color to match your Emacs theme background color.